# how to display portrait image in html page

Tags: html, image

How to display a portrait image in html? I used an `img` tag. My portrait image is being rotated 90 degrees and shown in landscape.

How can an image be shown in its original orientation?

Comment: Without more context it is not easy to help. If you have a simple html tag `<img src="yourPortraitImage.jpg">` AFAIK the image is displayed how it was taken - so a portrait image should be displayed as a portrait. If you add code and more information it is easier to help.

Comment: I am using the simple html tag <img src="yourPortraitImage.jpg"> however the portrait images are not shown properly.

Comment: From browsing the related questions i [found](http://sethfowler.org/blog/2013/09/13/new-in-firefox-26-css-image-orientation/) `A ... mismatch exists between the web, where the orientation of an image is determined by how its pixels are stored, and digital photography, which increasingly relies on metadata to mark the image as rotated, storing the pixels in the same orientation no matter what.` You might find more info in [extract image orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632356/) or [correct orientation in mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463126/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for your element:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
transform: rotate(90deg);`
```

Comment: I want to display landscape and portrait images both, this CSS is rotating landscape images also.