# System.Drawing.Graphics Drawimage rotates picture taken from IOS to 90 degree

Tags: c#, ios, image, system.drawing, bitmapimage

I have the following code which gets an image uploaded and draws it in 150 by 200 div using System.Drawing.Graphics but when the image is taken from IOS device the picture is rotated to 90 degree right.

FYI: I had the same issue drawing the image in JavaScript canvas and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242954/3038042) solution worked for me. Therefore I am looking for an equivalent solution in C#

```
     private System.Drawing.Image ResizeAndDraw(System.Drawing.Image objTempImage)
            {
                Size objSize = new Size(150, 200);
                Bitmap objBmp;
                objBmp = new Bitmap(objSize.Width, objSize.Height);

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(objBmp);
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, thumbSize.Width, thumbSize.Height);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,150,200);
                //g.DrawImage(objTempImage, rect, 0, 0, objTempImage.Width, objTempImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                g.DrawImage(objTempImage, rect);
                return objBmp;
            }
```

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem from the answer posted  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460026/3038042)  He  wrote a simple helper class that does all that:

[you can check the full source code here.](http://www.ryadel.com/en/change-image-orientation-iphone-andor-android-phone-pics-net-c/)

```
    private System.Drawing.Image ResizeAndDraw(System.Drawing.Image objTempImage)
        {
          // call image helper to fix the orientation issue 
            var temp = ImageHelper.RotateImageByExifOrientationData(objTempImage, true);
            Size objSize = new Size(150, 200);
            Bitmap objBmp;
            objBmp = new Bitmap(objSize.Width, objSize.Height);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(objBmp);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, thumbSize.Width, thumbSize.Height);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,150,200);
            //g.DrawImage(objTempImage, rect, 0, 0, objTempImage.Width, objTempImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.DrawImage(objTempImage, rect);
            return objBmp;
        }


using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;

public static class ImageHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the given image file according to Exif Orientation data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath">path of source file</param>
    /// <param name="targetFilePath">path of target file</param>
    /// <param name="targetFormat">target format</param>
    /// <param name="updateExifData">set it to TRUE to update image Exif data after rotation (default is TRUE)</param>
    /// <returns>The RotateFlipType value corresponding to the applied rotation. If no rotation occurred, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone will be returned.</returns>
    public static RotateFlipType RotateImageByExifOrientationData(string sourceFilePath, string targetFilePath, ImageFormat targetFormat, bool updateExifData = true)
    {
        // Rotate the image according to EXIF data
        var bmp = new Bitmap(sourceFilePath);
        RotateFlipType fType = RotateImageByExifOrientationData(bmp, updateExifData);
        if (fType != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
        {
            bmp.Save(targetFilePath, targetFormat);
        }
        return fType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the given bitmap according to Exif Orientation data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="img">source image</param>
    /// <param name="updateExifData">set it to TRUE to update image Exif data after rotation (default is TRUE)</param>
    /// <returns>The RotateFlipType value corresponding to the applied rotation. If no rotation occurred, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone will be returned.</returns>
    public static RotateFlipType RotateImageByExifOrientationData(Image img, bool updateExifData = true)
    {
        int orientationId = 0x0112;
        var fType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
        if (img.PropertyIdList.Contains(orientationId))
        {
            var pItem = img.GetPropertyItem(orientationId);
            fType = GetRotateFlipTypeByExifOrientationData(pItem.Value[0]);
            if (fType != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                img.RotateFlip(fType);
                // Remove Exif orientation tag (if requested)
                if (updateExifData) img.RemovePropertyItem(orientationId);
            }
        }
        return fType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the proper System.Drawing.RotateFlipType according to given orientation EXIF metadata
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orientation">Exif "Orientation"</param>
    /// <returns>the corresponding System.Drawing.RotateFlipType enum value</returns>
    public static RotateFlipType GetRotateFlipTypeByExifOrientationData(int orientation)
    {
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case 1:
            default:
                return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
            case 2:
                return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX;
            case 3:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
            case 4:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX;
            case 5:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX;
            case 6:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
            case 7:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX;
            case 8:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note:In linux the `pItem.Value[0]` may not same with windows.In my code,I use `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)?pItem.Value[0]: pItem.Value.Last()`